# javascript selectors document.object

Tags: javascript, selector

I am trying to select few elements into my html page and I'm wondering why I should use all the time that "document" when I'm targeting html elements for example:

//variable body

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

> in next variable why I cannot use something like: get all p tags from body

```
var selector = content.querySelectorAll("p");
```

> instead of using

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll("p");
```

Comment: why don't you use jquery?

Comment: You should really checkout the wonderful jquery library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in next variable why I cannot use something like: get all p tags from body

Because `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not an element. It works if you grab the one element that matched:

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
// ------------------------------------------------^^^
var paragraphs = content.querySelectorAll("p");
```

But just use `document.body` instead:

```
var paragraphs = document.body.querySelectorAll("p");
```

(Of course, as `p` elements cannot be outside of `body`, both of those are the same as `document.querySelectorAll` in this **specific** case.)

If you want all `p` elements that are **direct children** of `body`, then:

```
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("body > p");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements not one, you can use;

```
var selector = content[0].querySelectorAll("p");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElementsByTagName()` returns array.
So you should use `var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mainly because `document.getElementsByTagName` return a HTMLCollection.

By definition, a "HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list."

So, in your example, you need to use `var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];` or `document.body` (better)